# Matlab circle radius duplication

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry

I'm new to Matlab can anyone explain why the circle is measuring as 10 on the graph double to the radius. I expected it to be 5 matching the radius

```
xCenter = 5;
yCenter = 5;
theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
radius = 5;
x = radius * cos(theta) + xCenter;
y = radius * sin(theta) + yCenter;
plot(x, y);
axis square;
xlim([0 10]);
ylim([0 10]);
grid on;
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, the radius is 5 and the center is (5,5). So it fits in the square from (0,0), to (10,10). Diameter is 10, which is twice the radius. What do you find wrong?

Comment: Euh? What's the problem exactly? The radius is 5 as it should. What does "10 on the graph double to the radius" mean?

Comment: I thought it would reach 5 on the x and y axis having an radius of 5 to make this happen I have to set the radius to 2.5. Was just not what I expected. What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

If you want the circle to reach 5 on the x and y axes, then it should be centered at the origin.